# Drupal D3 module documentation

Tags: drupal, d3.js, drupal-7

I am attempting to create some visualisations in `Drupal`, and found the [D3 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3).  However, I can't find much documentation.  Could someone point me in the direction of a guide to using the module, or explain how to use it?

I have installed the module as described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2257739/), but I don't know how to get a chart to display on a page (I haven't used Drupal much either).

**Basically I would like to know:**

1. How does it work with Drupal?
2. What all Chart styles does it support?
3. How does it integrate with Drupal's Views and Panel in terms of generating visuals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [d3.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3) module indeed seems to suffer some documentation issues. Moreover it still doesn't have an official release so far (only dev versions). The 
d3.js library that this module integrates with seems to become more and more popular.

Refer to the [Maintenance Scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards) for over 20 criteria to consider when selecting a module to create charts. By doing so, you might want to consider other [charts related modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) that can be used for creating charts in Drupal.

The number of reported installs indicate that either the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module is often considered as a viable module for creating charts in Drupal. For both modules quite some documentation is available also.

The [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module's project page contains some information that indicates it is "being depreciated and users are recommended to move over to the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module". Though most recently some comments in the chart issue queue contain some details that illustrate that that depreciation is being reconsidered. Refer to that issue queue for more details on that.

If needed, do not hesitate to create an issue in the module's issue queue. As an alternative create a new question on this site (or Drupal Answers) and find a way to let me know about it (eg via some comment in any of my questions or answers around here).

**Disclosure**: I'm the maintainer of both modules [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), and the author of the documentation of [charts related modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) mentioned in my answer also.

**Note**: In a future release of the chart module, support for the d3.js (as a charting library) is expected to be added also.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.  I'll take another look into the Charts module.  I think the reason I went for the D3 module was because I like the look of d3, and have seen it used in several places.  If the Chart module gains support for d3, that would be great!

Comment: Trust me: some day D3 support will be added, it is part of my "Chart 2.0" plan. Module "charts" (with 's') will continue to support "common features supported by all its charting engines" (so that you can easily swap between either of them). While module "chart" will be rather the opposite: for each of the supported charting engines (like D3, or pChart, or SVG Graph, ...) you should be able to use any of the supported charting engine features. Which implies that swapping between any 2 combinations, you might loose features supported by the 1st engine, but not supported by the 2nd engine.

Answer (score 3):

I have downloaded the latest version of the library d3.zip in /sites/all/libraries/d3 and installed the module. Once it is enabled (D3, D3 Views and D3 Examples), you can see in yoursite/examples some examples for the module. With "D3 Views" enabled you have the possibility of setting the format "D3 Visualization" in a view. You can use the view in your page.
Before I have worked creating some graphics with the module forena and the library SVGGraph. It is very well documented. 
With d3 I have just started today testing but I got to create a graphic in the view how I told you above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with this module myself, lately, and hope to have a live example up soon. As user28577 posted above, you should be able to use D3 Views (following the instructions) to create a view to display one of stock options (such as a bar or pie chart). Depending upon your knowledge of using Views in Drupal, it should be fairly easy to either create a new content type, or use an existing one as a source for your data that will be charted using the D3 module.

One possible reason (since I can't see your issue) you may not be seeing content is how your theme loads external JavaScript. I found this by toggling through different themes in one of my test environments, where some would not load D3 through an external library. Once I downloaded the latest build of D3 and placed it in sites/all/libraries/d3, things worked fine. It also allows development without an internet connection.

Without a good knowledge of the Drupal API, it can be challenging to source your data to chart if building a custom visualization. Although it's not the "Drupal Way", one workaround may be enabling the PHP filter (part of Drupal core), and posting your visualization into an existing content type, such as a basic page. You should be able to view this fine. But keep in mind that all data must be edited manually, and be aware of possible security holes.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I'd like to add a few things for people continuing to read this.

1. I apologize for the 'work in progress' documentation, but the
   module itself has been a 'work in progress'. The module is now in
   alpha1, and so documentation is in the works.
2. The module takes a completely different approach to
   visualizations then that of modules like [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), and
   [chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart). In terms of the API itself, those modules take a more 'php in, js out' approach. That is to say, you build the visualization primarily in php, and the module will handle all the JS for you. What the d3 module does is let you add 'libraries' via the libraries module, which are actual d3 code snippets wrapped in some code that Drupal reads. You can add and remove them much like modules. You can also make libraries dependent on other libraries. These give module developers and d3.js developers the ability to customize and add in any d3.js code because it's not baked into the module. The downside is that there is a little less 'out-of-the-box' magic.
3. These libraries also have .info files which can contain mapping information to take data from views, for example, and map that data into your d3 drupal library. You then customize that mapping in the views settings.
4. There are a few libraries that ship with the d3 module, but there will soon be a few larger and extensible repositories of libraries that are Drupal-ready. The idea is that there two huge communities - The Drupal community that builds thousands of modules for use, and the d3.js community that builds thousands of visualizations for use. Those will meet together and all of those libraries will be ready to add to a Drupal site just like you would a module.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly documentation for the `D3` module is a "work in progress". You can view the progress [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2257739), but it looks like you will need to rely on trial-and-error and results from other community members.

Comment: Thanks, but I have read that documentation.  I was hoping someone, perhaps community members, could point me in the right direction.  I didn't meant to disparage the efforts of those who have contributed to the module or documentation.  I was hoping to find someone who has used the module and could give me a bit of help. I suspect my lack of Drupal knowledge is as much of a problem and perhaps the documentation which exists is aimed at those with more knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Basically D3 modules provide UI reach visualization of following types

- Chord Digram
- Force-Directed Graph
- Treemap
- Scatterplot Matrix
- Bubble Chart
- Pie Charts / Donut Charts
- Multiple Line Graphs
- and few more

Through library D3 gets well integrated with Drupal at presentation as well as Business layer. It is always much ahead than `Charts` module in terms of its styles and usability aspect.

D3 also avails VIEWS style formatters which can applied on the data manipulated through **VIEWS** and **PANEL** modules.

Even Visualizations build through D# and Drupal can be available for the DOWNLOAD apart from presenting onto the page.

Please visit - [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juwsrW8ZouU) for further information.

Comment: I'm attempting to use the module (alpha) but unable to access the d3 library ... my page gets a "d3 is not defined" error. I've posted an error to the Drupal forum but if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it.